# <Link> onClick react-notifications not showing, but it runs the function

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router, react-router-dom, react-notifications

I created a survey page, but when someone doesn't have credits I want to show a notification to the user using react-notifications, I've already tested the button and standalone it works, but when I added it to the  tag using react-router-dom on an onClick event, the functions runs, but the notifications doesn't appear. Here's the code:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import 'react-notifications/lib/notifications.css';
import { connect } from 'react-redux';
import { Link } from 'react-router-dom';
import {NotificationContainer, NotificationManager} from 'react-notifications';

class Button extends Component {
  createNotification = () => {
    return () => {
      switch (this.props.auth.credits) {
        case 0:
          console.log(this.props.auth.credits);
          NotificationManager.error('You have no credits', 'Click to close!', 5000, () => {
          });
          break;
      }
    };
  };

  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <div  className="fixed-action-btn">
          <Link to="/surveys/new" className="btn-floating btn-large red" onClick={this.createNotification()}>
            <i className="material-icons">add</i>
          </Link>
        </div>
        <NotificationContainer/>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

function mapStateToProps({ auth }){
  return { auth };
}

export default connect(mapStateToProps)(Button);
```

So, when I test this on:

```
import React from 'react';
import Surveys from './surveys/Surveys';
import Button from '../utilities/addButton';


const Board = () => {
  return (
    <div>
      <Surveys />
      <Button />

    </div>
  );
};

export default Board;
```

It shows the button, and when clicked without credits, it console.logs the 0 credits, but, it just redirects to the referenced page without showing the notification created.

On my side, it doesn't appear an error neither in the terminal nor in the console or network. But still, the notification is processed but not shown.

**So my question is:** Is it possible to make the notification appear when the  tag redirects to the new page, the only way that I see a solutions if it's not possible is making a conditional to stop the  tag to make the change, am I wrong?

Thanks in advance.
Sorry if my question is not properly presented or written, is my first question here.

Answer (score 0):

`onClick` prop for `Link` accept function reference. so try replacing

```
 <Link to="/surveys/new" className="btn-floating btn-large red" onClick={this.createNotification}>
     <i className="material-icons">add</i>
 </Link>
```

Comment: I'm sorry, just tested it and this didn't work for me, it also stopped making the console.log.

Answer (score 0):

This may be a Very Late reply but for those who didnt answer its because Link doesnt accept onCLick... try  for html or  with react or reactbootstrap package